# Pandas rolling average window for dates excluding row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": [pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-05")],
    "numbers": [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
)
```

If I have the following df and I would like to get the rolling mean for the values of `numbers` that are before each rows `date` column, how would I do that?

I know I can do

`df["av"] = df.shift(1).rolling(window=3).mean()`

but this does not shift dynamically so it includes today.

My expected output for the new `av` column for a 3 day window over the sample df would be

```
    date    numbers av
0   2022-01-01  1   NaN
1   2022-01-01  2   NaN
2   2022-01-01  3   NaN
3   2022-01-03  4   2.0
4   2022-01-03  7   2.0
5   2022-01-05  5   5.5
```

Comment: How is count `5.5` ?

Comment: The average of the last three days. In that row it is both number values on January 3rd. (7 +4)/2 @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need rolling means per unique `date`s with add excluded dates shifted by 1 day.

Here is used alternative solution for means by definition - `sum / count`.

```
df1 = (df.groupby('date')['numbers']
         .agg(['sum','size'])
         .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
         .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
         .sum())

df['av'] = df['date'].map(df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).shift())
print (df)
        date  numbers   av
0 2022-01-01        1  NaN
1 2022-01-01        2  NaN
2 2022-01-01        3  NaN
3 2022-01-03        4  2.0
4 2022-01-03        7  2.0
5 2022-01-05        5  5.5
```

**Explanation**:

First are aggregate `sum` and `size` for count:

```
print (df.groupby('date')['numbers'].agg(['sum','size']))
            sum  size
date                 
2022-01-01    6     3
2022-01-03   11     2
2022-01-05    5     1
```

Added missing consecutives dates by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
print (df.groupby('date')['numbers']
         .agg(['sum','size'])
         .asfreq('d', fill_value=0))
            sum  size
date                 
2022-01-01    6     3
2022-01-02    0     0
2022-01-03   11     2
2022-01-04    0     0
2022-01-05    5     1
```

Use rolling per 3 days by `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('date')['numbers']
         .agg(['sum','size'])
         .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
         .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
         .sum())
print (df1)
             sum  size
date                  
2022-01-01   6.0   3.0
2022-01-02   6.0   3.0
2022-01-03  17.0   5.0
2022-01-04  11.0   2.0
2022-01-05  16.0   3.0
```

Divide columns from `df1` for averages:

```
print (df1['sum'].div(df1['size']))
date
2022-01-01    2.000000
2022-01-02    2.000000
2022-01-03    3.400000
2022-01-04    5.500000
2022-01-05    5.333333
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Exclude day by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) by one day:

```
print (df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).shift())
date
2022-01-01    NaN
2022-01-02    2.0
2022-01-03    2.0
2022-01-04    3.4
2022-01-05    5.5
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Last for new column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
print (df['date'].map(df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).shift()))
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    5.5
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Any sudo code explanation of what each step is doing? For future readers? @jezrael

Comment: Hey @jezrael - if I wanted to expand on this question and groupby two things initially - say date, and day of the week - then map this back onto the original df. how would I do that?

Comment: I can open this into a new question if you would prefer...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777822/pandas-rolling-averages-for-dates-after-group-by

Answer (score 2):

answer above seems too complex ,here is a simple one

```
   def function1(ss:pd.Series):
        return ss.loc[ss.index!=ss.index.max()].mean()
    
    df1.assign(av=df1.rolling('4d',on='date').numbers.apply(function1))  
     


         numbers   av
date                    
2022-01-01        1  NaN
2022-01-01        2  NaN
2022-01-01        3  NaN
2022-01-03        4  2.0
2022-01-03        7  2.0
2022-01-05        5  5.5
```

Comment: @BenMuller  a new solution