# Pandas rolling averages for dates after group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": [pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-01-05")],
    "numbers": [1,2,4,4,11,7,5],
    "grouper": [1, 0, 1, 0,1, 0, 0]
    }
)
```

If I have the following df and I would like to get the rolling mean for the values of numbers that are before each rows date column, how would I do that? eg. the rolling averages for the past 3 days for grouped by ["grouper", "date"]

I know I can do something like this, but not even close to a solution -

I am looking to build on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74767290/pandas-rolling-average-window-for-dates-excluding-row)

```
df["av"] = df.shift(1).rolling(window=3).mean()
```

but this does not shift dynamically so it includes today.

My expected output for the new av column for a 3 day window grouped by the two columns of the sample df would be

```
    date    numbers grouper av
0   2022-01-01  1   1   NaN
1   2022-01-01  2   0   NaN
2   2022-01-01  4   1   NaN
3   2022-01-03  4   0   2.0
4   2022-01-03  11  1   2.5
5   2022-01-03  7   0   2.0
6   2022-01-05  5   0   5.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need average by definition - `sum / count`.

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
         .agg(['sum','size'])
         .unstack()
         .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
         .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
         .sum()
         .shift()
         .stack()
         )

df = df.join(df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).rename('aw'), on=['date','grouper'])
print (df)
        date  numbers  grouper   aw
0 2022-01-01        1        1  NaN
1 2022-01-01        2        0  NaN
2 2022-01-01        4        1  NaN
3 2022-01-03        4        0  2.0
4 2022-01-03       11        1  2.5
5 2022-01-03        7        0  2.0
6 2022-01-05        5        0  5.5
```

**Explanation**:

First aggregate `sum` and count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             )
                    sum  size
date       grouper           
2022-01-01 0          2     1
           1          5     2
2022-01-03 0         11     2
           1         11     1
2022-01-05 0          5     1
```

Then for DatatimeIndex reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             .unstack()
             )
             sum       size     
grouper        0     1    0    1
date                            
2022-01-01   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-03  11.0  11.0  2.0  1.0
2022-01-05   5.0   NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Add missing consecutive datetimes by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             .unstack()
             .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
             )
             sum       size     
grouper        0     1    0    1
date                            
2022-01-01   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-02   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
2022-01-03  11.0  11.0  2.0  1.0
2022-01-04   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
2022-01-05   5.0   NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Then use rolling with `sum` (processing sum and counts):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             .unstack()
             .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
             .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
             .sum()
             )
             sum       size     
grouper        0     1    0    1
date                            
2022-01-01   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-02   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-03  13.0  16.0  3.0  3.0
2022-01-04  11.0  11.0  2.0  1.0
2022-01-05  16.0  11.0  3.0  1.0
```

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             .unstack()
             .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
             .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
             .sum()
             .shift()
             )
             sum       size     
grouper        0     1    0    1
date                            
2022-01-01   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-01-02   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-03   2.0   5.0  1.0  2.0
2022-01-04  13.0  16.0  3.0  3.0
2022-01-05  11.0  11.0  2.0  1.0
```

Reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['date','grouper'])['numbers']
             .agg(['sum','size'])
             .unstack()
             .asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
             .rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
             .sum()
             .shift()
             .stack()
             )
                     sum  size
date       grouper            
2022-01-02 0         2.0   1.0
           1         5.0   2.0
2022-01-03 0         2.0   1.0
           1         5.0   2.0
2022-01-04 0        13.0   3.0
           1        16.0   3.0
2022-01-05 0        11.0   2.0
           1        11.0   1.0
```

For averages divide columns:

```
print (df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).rename('aw'))
date        grouper
2022-01-02  0           2.000000
            1           2.500000
2022-01-03  0           2.000000
            1           2.500000
2022-01-04  0           4.333333
            1           5.333333
2022-01-05  0           5.500000
            1          11.000000
Name: aw, dtype: float64
```

And append to original:

```
df = df.join(df1['sum'].div(df1['size']).rename('aw'), on=['date','grouper'])
print (df)
        date  numbers  grouper   aw
0 2022-01-01        1        1  NaN
1 2022-01-01        2        0  NaN
2 2022-01-01        4        1  NaN
3 2022-01-03        4        0  2.0
4 2022-01-03       11        1  2.5
5 2022-01-03        7        0  2.0
6 2022-01-05        5        0  5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    return ss.loc[ss.index!=ss.index.max()].mean()

df.assign(av=df.groupby('grouper').apply(lambda dd:dd
                                         .rolling('4d',on='date').numbers.apply(function1))
          .droplevel(0))


    date  numbers  grouper   av
0 2022-01-01        1        1  NaN
1 2022-01-01        2        0  NaN
2 2022-01-01        4        1  NaN
3 2022-01-03        4        0  2.0
4 2022-01-03       11        1  2.5
5 2022-01-03        7        0  2.0
6 2022-01-05        5        0  5.5
```